# How to calulate a number in a table from a different field in the same table?

Tags: sql, mysql, calculated-columns

Say I have a basic table, products, with 3 fields, productname, cost, and costnotax.

Is it possible to automatically fill in the costnotax field by subtracting a percentage from the cost field?

Comment: Are you asking for information about triggers, computed columns, or an update statement to do such?

Comment: Or a view with a computed column?

Comment: Not an update, I mean while I insert a new record, during the original insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - simply something like this to calculate what the original cost was if you've got, say, 6% tax

```
UPDATE mytable SET costnotax=cost/1.06
```

However, there's little point in storing it when you can select it just as easily

```
SELECT cost, cost/1.06 AS costnotax FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Why are you dividing cost by 1.06...how does that equate to subtracting say 12%?

Its probably really obvious...but I can´t see it at the moment...

Comment: if you wanted to *add* 12% to a base price, you'd multiply by 1.12. So, to reverse that operation and get a base price from a taxed price, you would divide by 1.12

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here's two examples, using where the tax is 25% on the original price.
This is for the **whole table**:

```
UPDATE table SET costnotax = cost / 1.25;
```

And this is for **specific** rows:

```
UPDATE table SET costnotax = cost / 1.25 WHERE productname = 'Piglet with cream';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it for each new or updated record , then it should be `BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE` trigger. If you need to it once for all/specific records in the table, use `UPDATE ...`.  If all you need is to show costnotax, then it doesn't have to be a column at all, you can just query it like `SELECT cost/1.25 as costnotax FROM ...`